# NameError: global name 'b' is not defined

Tags: python, global-variables, getopt

I have an script wih the following structure:

```
def func():
    bfile=open(b, 'r')
    cfile=open(c, 'r')
    dfile=open(d, 'r')

if __name__=='__main__':
    if len(sys.argv)==1:
        print 'guidence'
        sys.exit()
    else:
        opts,args=getopt.getopt(sys.argv,'b:c:d:a')
        a=False
        for opt,arg in opts:
            if opt=='-a':
                a=True
            elif opt=='-b':
                b=arg
            elif opt=='-c':
                c=arg
            elif opt=='-d':
                d=arg
        func()
```

I run it in this way:

```
# python script.py -b file1 -c file1 -d file1

in func()
NameError: global name 'b' is not defined
```

I also define a global file1. but no work.

## Update

I know where the problem is:
the result of `print opts` is `[]`.
It has not values.
why?

Comment: You forgot the `def` before `func()`

Comment: Sorry guys; clearly I can't answer this question! Someone else have a go!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two issues.

First, `getopt` stops if it encounters a non-option. Since `sys.argv[0]` is the script name, it's a non-option and the parsing stops there.
You want to pass `sys.argv[1:]` to `getopt`.

This is what's causing `print opts` to show `[]`, and since `opts` is empty the global variables are never created, which is where the complaint that they don't exist come from.

Second, since `-a` wants a parameter, you need a colon after it.

In all, this should work:

```
opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], 'b:c:d:a:')
```

Also, you shouldn't pass parameters in globals.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the filenames to the function. In Your case it should look like this:

```
def func(b, c, d):
  bfile = open(b, 'r')
  cfile = open(c, 'r')
  dfile = open(d, 'r')
```

You can call it with:

```
b = 'nameB.txt'
c = 'nameC.txt'
d = 'nameD.txt'
func(b, c, d)
```

Comment: This is not the reason for the ``NameError`` error.

Comment: here is the problem of your asnwer: `'abc.txt'`

Comment: That's an example of how `open` function work. In earlier edit it looked like You were trying to pass noncreated file as a filename